# Angular 2 : Trigger notification on one port and Show notifications on another port

Tags: server, notifications, angular2-routing

Im trying to build a push notification in angular 2 using this plugin (angular2-notifications)

> npm install --save angular2-notifications

My scenario is like, i have 2 URLS: 1 for admin and 1 for Employee.

When an admin in URL (say)  localhost:1000/admin/dashboard ,

clicks on notify button (  when a notify() is called ),

an Employee which runs on different port and URL (localhost:2000/dashboard) should get a push notification.

1) How to achieve the same!!

2) Does this plugin support or display the push notification on our mobile devices?

3) Currently what i have tried is :

> npm install --save angular2-notifications

in **app.module.ts**

```
 import { PushNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications';     //import the module
```

in **component.ts**

```
constructor(private _pushNotifications: PushNotificationsService){
_pushNotifications.requestPermission(); // request for permission as soon as component loads
}

notify(){ //our function to be called on click
let options = { //set options
  body: "Your order # 1234 is ready, please collect",
  icon: "assets/images/ironman.png" //adding an icon
}
let notify = this._pushNotifications.create('Order ready', options).subscribe( 
    res => console.log(res),
    err => console.log(err)
);
}
```

**.html**

```
 <button (click)="notify()">Show Notification</button>
```

I need to trigger the notification on seperate port running on same server.

What are the steps to do the same